# Pandas how do I prevent myself from iterating through rows?

Tags: python, pandas

I have the following dataframe

```
Charge_type Amount Quantity
Credit        2.5    3 
Credit        3.24   2
Debit         5.98   6
```

I need the following output, if Charge_type is a 'credit' then multiply 'Amount' * -1 and 'Quantity' * -1 to get the following result:

```
Charge_type Amount Quantity
Credit       -2.5    -3 
Credit       -3.24   -2
Debit         5.98    6
```

I have no idea where to begin, everywhere I looked online says not to iterate in pandas. Sorry I'm still such a beginner with Python and Pandas. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One option is to use [`loc`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html#pandas-dataframe-loc):

```
df.loc[df['Charge_type'].eq('Credit'), ['Amount', 'Quantity']] *= -1
```

The first part creates a Boolean index `df['Charge_type'].eq('Credit')` (to select rows based on where Charge_type is 'Credit').

The second part choses the columns to affect `['Amount', 'Quantity']` in this case, 'Amount' and 'Quantity'.

Lastly, mutate using the shortcut operator `*=` to negate the values.

`df`:

```
  Charge_type  Amount  Quantity
0      Credit   -2.50        -3
1      Credit   -3.24        -2
2       Debit    5.98         6
```

Answer (score 2):

You can create a masking for the column `Charge_type`, and use `.loc` along with column name to access the column where the masking has `True` value, and then assign the new value accordingly:

```py
mask = df['Charge_type'] == 'Credit'
df.loc[mask, 'Amount'] = -df['Amount']
df.loc[mask, 'Quantity'] = -df['Quantity']
```

**OUTPUT**:

```py
  Charge_type  Amount  Quantity
0      Credit   -2.50        -3
1      Credit   -3.24        -2
2       Debit    5.98         6
```

Comment: Thanks so much! All the comments were so helpful!

Answer (score 1):

I think combining the approaches from the other two answers (already upvoted both) is most readable:

```
mask = df['Charge_type'] == 'Credit'
df.loc[mask, ['Amount', 'Quantity']] *= -1
```

Output:

```
  Charge_type  Amount  Quantity
0      Credit   -2.50        -3
1      Credit   -3.24        -2
2       Debit    5.98         6
```